# C# Connecting with remote mysql database, getting the error “Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts”

Tags: c#, mysql-error-1064

I was looking on many posts about this problem but not found an answer.

I try to connect to mysql DB that exist on some server, I use with the following code from https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2014/ and https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL

```
private string server = "xx.xxx.xxx.xx";
private string database = "testDB";
private string username = user;
private string password = password;
string connectionString;
connectionString = string.Format("Server={0},3306; Database=
{1}; User Id={2}; password={3};", server, database, username, 
password);

connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
try
{
    connection.Open();
}
catch (MySqlException ex)
{
   return false;
}
```

I install MySql.Data.dll from nuget console and open the port 3306(tcp) in the server.

When I try to open connection it gives me an error "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts".

Someone has an idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152607/discussion-on-question-by-tal-sshh-c-connecting-with-remote-mysql-database-get). As should be clear from the sheer number of comments that have been required to attempt to nail the question down to an answerable state, there are not enough details here.

Comment: I voted to reopen this question because there is an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 4):

Your connection string is not formatted correctly.
By separating entries with commas, you telling that there are multiple servers, which obviously is not the case. If you need to specify the port, try with:

```
connectionString = string.Format("Server={0}; Port=3306; Database=
{1}; Uid={2}; Pwd={3};", server, database, username, 
password);
```

But it is not necessary as 3306 is the default port on which MySQL server accepts connections. 
Here you can find [more examples](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/).

Comment: Also, "User Id" must be "Uid" and "password" must be "Pwd" ...

Comment: still not working!

Comment: @Fildor Nice catch - thanks. I updated my answer.

Comment: @tal_sshh Aww, I see. Great explanation of the problem... As per Fildor comment, you also need to change the "User id=" and "Password="

Comment: same problem....

Comment: @tal_sshh Yes because you are using the wrong Connector. MySqlConnection won't work with MS SQL Server.

Comment: @ Fildor 
I looking on google and this is what i found.. Can you tell me what I should use?

Comment: See https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C

Comment: @BozhidarStoinev I am afraid your answer is void now. Obviously OP used MySQL Connectors for MS SQL Database, so the connection string was in fact ok. I am not retracting my upvote because it was the most likely solution at the time given the infos you had.

Comment: @Fildor thanks, i will check your link.

Comment: @Fildor Indeed. Big mess...

Comment: @Fildor Thanks man. I got confused, now it's work perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string should actually be fine.

Your problem is `MySqlConnection`. You have a MS SQL Server, not MySQL.

You should be using `SqlConnection` from namespace `System.Data.SqlClient` instead.

Your port probably isn't right, since it is the default MySQL-Port. Just try to leave out the port, then it will try to use the default port for MS SQL Server.